# Improving SharePoint 2010 performance in a VM

Tags: visual-studio, virtual-machine, performance

I have created a virtual machine with windows server 2008, Visual Studio 2010, and SharePoint 2010 for development and testing.  The machine is configured in VMWare with 40gb hdd, 2gb ram, and 4 processors, but it is running VERY slowly.  I can't get anything done.

The host machine is a very high-end laptop with an i7 processor, running windows 7.

Does anyone have any tips for speeding this environment up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First off you need to bump up your RAM. I'd do at *least* 4GB for a dev machine. Then you need to disable any services you don't need (search is a big one). Also, make sure you're making efficient use of your app pools (no need for a least privileges model in dev unless you explicitly need it). Not sure if your VM is also a DC or not - if it is then you might be better off separating that role out to a different server.

Comment: "no need for a least privileges model in dev". I beg to differ. From a configuration standpoint Dev should mirror Test and Prod environments to catch, in your case security, issues as early as possible. I agree on the recommendation to increase memory though.

Answer (score 3):

I agree on increasing memory and invest in a secondary SSD drive. If you're going to develop on the machine and use SharePoint Server 4GB is the least amount you should have dedicated to the VM.

Another tip is to NOT use a lot of CPU's and cores for your VM - instead of increasing performance you will more likely decrease the VM performance since it has to switch between the cores. I always use a single core for my laptop VM's.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from memory, constantly resetting app pools and spinning SharePoint is very I/O intensive. The biggest performance improvement I have experienced myself was running the main SharePoint VM on an SSD drive. I left the domain controller on a different hard drive.

http://planetwilson.blogspot.com/2010/03/ssd-goodness-and-sharepoint-virtual.html

Answer (score 1):

Well I believe there are lot of problems that contribute to performance bottlenecks in SharePoint however it is a very useful extremely popular product that improves effectiveness of organizations through content management and enterprise search, shared business processes, and information-sharing across boundaries for better business insight.

The SharePoint performance problems occur primarily due to the following reasons:

- BLOBs overwhelm SQL Server
- Too many database trips for lists

You can dramatically improve SharePoint performance if you use a few of intelligent techniques which are:

- Externalize Documents (BLOBs)
- Cache Lists and BLOBs

StorageEdge provides precisely such a blob caching facility. It offers a unique combination of externalization and BLOB caching for effective blob management and access from a single interface. It makes use of NCache® technology to let you cache frequently used BLOBs in a distributed fashion with high availability, complete replication and failover. A distributed cache can give your SharePoint infrastructure a significant scalability boost because it keeps things distributed across multiple servers and still giving one logical view. But the cache actually lives on multiple servers and that’s what allows the cache to really scale.